# Is this implementation of a central static class correct?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

So, I'm starting a new project, trying to implement a few things I've learnt over the last few years, the first of which is using Castle for IoC.

I want a central 'Core' class, which would be shared across numerous end projects (Console apps, websites). So I guess, two questions here:

a) Is this approach correct
b) Is my implementation correct.

I know this is a very small class, but I want to get it correct from the start.

```
public static class Global {
        static IWindsorContainer _Container;
        static int ContainerInitalised = 0;
        static string ServicesFile;

        public static IWindsorContainer Container{
            get{
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref ContainerInitalised, 1, 0) == 0) {
                    Collection<IWindsorInstaller> installers = new Collection<IWindsorInstaller> {
                        { FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("Installers")) }
                    };
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServicesFile)) {
                        installers.Add(Configuration.FromXmlFile(ServicesFile));
                    }
                    _Container = new WindsorContainer().Install(installers.ToArray());
                }
                return _Container;
            }
        }

        public static void Initialise(string servicesFile) {
            ServicesFile = servicesFile;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS per David your idea go toward a ServiceLocator solution which is the worst way to use an IoC container.

Also abstracting IoC container with a common interface is a bad idea because you end up loosing special container features: speacially an interface not exposing a release method leads to a disaster using a mature IoC container such windosr which is based on RRR pattern.

The correct approach has been clearly described by Krzysztof on [his NDC presentations](http://kozmic.pl/presentations/)

- Plug the IoC container into your app using a factory as per MVC3 implementation
- Do one Resolve only as soon as possible: a single Resolve for non web-app, one resolve per request for a web scenario
- Release ALWAYS what you resolved

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to clean it up a bit by taking a step toward a "service locator" implementation.  (Indeed, there's [a common library](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) that does exactly this.)

For example, you can abstract the IoC container behind an interface and have a static factory that provides the current implementation (to replace your generic `Global` class and make it more targeted).  Something like this:

```
public interface IoCContainer
{
    object GetInstance(Type serviceType);
    object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key);
    IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType);
    T GetInstance<T>();
    T GetInstance<T>(string key);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllInstances<T>();
}

public static class IoCContainerFactory
{
    private static IoCContainer current;

    public static IoCContainer Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (current == null)
                throw new DomainException("IoC Container Not Initialized.  This application must call a bootstrap method in an IoC implementation project.");
            return current;
        }
    }

    public static void Initialize(IoCContainer container)
    {
        current = container;
    }
}
```

Then in another project I implement the `IoCContainer` interface (I use StructureMap, you use Castle... there are plenty of options).  Also in that other project I have an `Initializer` class which will bootstrap the container implementation (since configuration is different for any implementation) and, as a last step, initialize this "global" factory:

```
IoCContainerFactory.Initialize(new IoCContainerImplementation(ObjectFactory.Container));
```

(In the case of the above line of code, `IoCContainerImplementation` is my implementation of the aforementioned interface, and `ObjectFactory` is from StructureMap and was just configured/bootstrapped in previous lines of code before this one.)

Of course, with this approach, there's a bit of a trade-off.  By abstracting my IoC container behind a common interface, I can only do things which are common across many IoC container implementations.  For my needs, all I want is to call a method to resolve dependencies.  But other things like decorating classes/properties with attributes (if your choice of IoC container has that feature) would require either tightly coupling to that specific container or expanding this implementation to include custom attributes which make use of that feature in some way.